# turning optimisation off in part of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, optimization

I started using vmprotect sdk to protect my app, but I've faced few issues, biggest one is compiler optimisations - it's optimising out my markers, take a look at example:

```
void *CaptureInterface( char *pszInterfaceName )
{
    VMProtectBeginMutation( "capture_interface" );

    void* ptr = 12345;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    VMProtectEnd( );
    return ptr;

}
```

I tried various combinations, VMProtectEnd before return, after, but compiler keeps optimising out VMProtectEnd function so call isn't visible in disassembly so markers begin being unpaired and I can't protect my app. Is there any way to turn optimisation related things for 1 or 2 functions? Or is there any other way to tell compiler to not touch that marker but keep optimising others?

Comment: If `VMProtetEnd()` is a call to an external library, there's no way the compiler could optimize it out. Are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: If optimisations have impact on library operations, it is a bug in the library and should be brought to the library writers.

Comment: @Roger True in the good old days, not as true in days of LTO I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `#pragma optimize` preprocessor directive.

See, e.g., https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

Comment: I know about it, but it has to be used outside of functions, so I can't write pragma optimize(off) before vmprotect call and pragma optimize on after, this is last thing I want to do, I'm asking if there are any ways to exclude marker from optimization, but anyways thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These things never help much anyhow and personally I'd be worried that if they can't get such a basic thing right, what else they will do to your code which will be *really* fun to debug.

But anyhow, if you want to avoid them optimizing the code away, I'd probably do some inline assembly to make the call:

```
static void foo() {

}

void test() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    foo();
    std::cout << "Goodbye world\n";
}

void test2() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    __asm {
        call foo;
    }
    std::cout << "Goodbye world\n";
}
```

The call to foo in test2 is not optimized away in VS2015 with /O2. That's limited to x86 code though, because as far as I know Microsoft does not support inline assembly any longer for x64..

If the call to the function is not just a hint to the runtime, but the call *itself* is what's important, you could use a function pointer to achieve this in a portable manner. I don't know enough about the innards of the used library to know whether that's the case though.

Comment: I know that nothing can protect my app against cracking, but vmprotect definitely will protect it from cracking by _noobs_ and slow down others, thank you for this inline asm idea!